# SQLAlchemy fails to insert decimal only on temp table

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

Trying to insert into temp tables with SQLAlchemy (plugged into PYODBC/sql server) and inserting more than one row with decimal values and `fast_executemany=True` throws:

> ProgrammingError("(pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('Converting decimal loses precision', 'HY000')")

This happens only in temp table with `fast_executemany=True` and multiple rows being inserted at once with one column being decimal. Inserting one at a time, turning `fast_executemany` off or inserting into a regular table works perfectly.

I've built a simple example:

```
CONNSTR = "mssql+pyodbc://user:PASSWORD@SERVER?driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server&trusted_connection=yes"

def test():
    data = [(1, Decimal('41763.9907359278'), Decimal('227367.1749095026')), (1027, Decimal('3117.1592020142'), Decimal('16970.1139430488'))]
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(CONNSTR, fast_executemany=True, connect_args={'connect_timeout': 10})
    #this will fail
    insert(engine, data, "#temp_table_test")
    #this will work
    insert(engine, data, "regular_table_test") 

def insert(engine, data, table_name):
    try:
        with engine.begin() as con:
            con.execute(f"""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {table_name};""")
            con.execute(f"""
                CREATE TABLE {table_name} (
                    [id_column] INT NULL UNIQUE,
                    [usd_price] DECIMAL(38,20) NULL,
                    [brl_price] DECIMAL(38,20) NULL,
                )
            """)
            sql_insert_prices = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} VALUES (?,?,?)"
            con.execute(sql_insert_prices, data)
            print(f"Insert em {table_name} worked!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{e!r}")
        print(f"Insert em {table_name} failed!")
```

---

While obviously related to the minimal conversion mechanisms done by fast execute, I can't find out why this runs differently depending on the type of table. Every other question here citing this particular exception is caused by other factors not present here I think so I'm really at a loss.

EDIT: so the original test with just one decimal column ran fine (I assumed reducing the number of columns wouldn't change the output), but adding another decimal column brings me back to square one with the same error message

Comment: Can you post a complete repro, including the relevant info in the connection string (ie the driver and version)?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft added

Comment: Does `insert(engine, data, "##temp_table_test")` work?

Comment: @GordThompson yes it does. This already solves my problem (so please post it as an answer) I just have no idea as to why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fast_executemany=True` asks the ODBC driver what the column types are, and the default mechanism used by Microsoft's ODBC drivers for SQL Server is to call a system stored procedure named `sp_describe_undeclared_parameters`. That stored procedure has some difficulties with #local_temp tables that do not occur with regular tables or ##global_temp tables. Details in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/295).

As mentioned in the related [wiki entry](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Tips-and-Tricks-by-Database-Platform#using-fast_executemany-with-a-temporary-table), workarounds include

- using `Cursor.setinputsizes()` to explicitly declare the column types,
- using a ##global_temp table instead of a #local_temp table, or
- adding `UseFMTONLY=Yes` to the ODBC connection string.

The easiest way to enable `UseFMTONLY` with SQLAlchemy is to use a [pass-through pyodbc connection string](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mssql.html#pass-through-exact-pyodbc-string), for example

```py
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

connection_string = (
    "DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;"
    "SERVER=192.168.0.199;"
    "DATABASE=test;"
    "UID=scott;PWD=tiger^5HHH;"
    "UseFMTONLY=Yes;"
)

connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})

engine = create_engine(connection_url, fast_executemany=True)
```

Comment: This was exactly the problem I was facing and this Github issue shines a light on the problem as well. Thank you